# Accessing a framework from another framework and an app target

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks

I'm not sure how to correctly configure build settings for how I want to share a framework between another framework and my app target - in this case the shared framework is the Facebook SDK, but I'm not sure whether that is relevant to the problems I'm running into or not.

How I would *like* for things to work: 
I'd like for my framework to include the Facebook SDK, and because my app is importing my framework, it can access the Facebook SDK. Unfortunately I can't build using this configuration.

First, I receive an `unresolved identifier` build error when attempting to reference anything from the Facebook SDK from "My App".

If I include `import FBSDKLoginKit`, that build error goes away, but I fail to compile with `FBSDKLoginKit is not a dylib`.  If I then include the Facebook SDK frameworks in the "My App" target build settings, I can finally build and run, but at run time I get console logs warning that all of the FBSDK classes are implemented in both "My App" and "My Framework" and that "one of the two will be used. Which one is undefined."  This makes complete sense, as I've now basically compiled the Facebook SDK twice.

[image]

I think what I've described above is an umbrella framework, which I understand is discouraged by Apple.  Given that "My App" needs to access "FBSDK" and "My Framework", and "My Framework" needs to access "FBSDK", what is the correct way configure the build settings for "My App" and "My Framework" without getting console logs about duplicate implementations?

Comment: Not a Cocoapod, right? Is “My Framework” brought into a workspace?

Comment: Right, I'm not using Cocoapods.  I have a project with two targets, "My App" and "My Framework".  "My Framework" will eventually be shared code with other similar apps, which is why its been pulled apart from "My App".

Comment: In project, go to your framework's target and select the General tab. Under “Linked Frameworks and Libraries” does setting “FBSDK” to “Optional” work?

Comment: just add your framework and FBSDK to your app target. Your framework can call all FBSDK function as normal

Comment: @SushiGrassJacob I still get the console messages about duplicate implementations.

Comment: @ABáo if the framework doesn't include FBSDK, it can't call any FBSDK functions.  I get framework linker errors if I try to import FBSDK and without importing FBSDK I get unresolved identifiers when calling any FBSDK functions.

Comment: I suppose this is out of my league. We had a redundant analytics SDK that we were able to resolve by marking it as optional. We are using Cocoapods, though. Gooooooooooood luck!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's a known issue with cocoapods, they already solved it but it wasn't released yet. I guess it will be fixed in the next cocoapods update.

There is nothing wrong with your implementation.

source: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/pull/7601